# Apply Patch in yocto raspberry-image

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, yocto, patch

I want to apply rt-patch in raspberry-pi by following (https://docs.yoctoproject.org/3.1.20/kernel-dev/kernel-dev-common.html#using-traditional-kernel-development-to-patch-the-kernel).
So in order to achieve that I created my own meta-layer and put that patch in bblayer of build directory. In order to apply patching i did following steps.

1. I downloaded patch file from (https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.4/older/patch-5.4.70-rt40.patch.gz) unzip and rename with (patch-5.4.70-rt40.patch)
2. I put that patch file in yocto/meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.

3.And given patch file's path in yocto/meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_4.12.bbappend by following lines
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI_append  = "file://patch-5.4.70-rt40.patch"

when i am trying to bake my recipe : bitbake core-image-base then following error is showing

```
Loading cache: 100% |############################################| Time: 0:00:01
Loaded 3004 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: No recipes available for:
  /home/nikita/yocto/meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_4.12.bbappend
 
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Can anyone please suggest me how can I apply rt-patch in my raspberry-image with above method by solving corresponding error.

Thanks in advance
Nikita Gupta

Comment: What poky version you are using ?

Comment: "5.4%" version i am using

Comment: I am asking about the poky version (dunfell ?)

Comment: my-yocto-3.1.19 similar to dunfell